# If field is NOT null, then hide an object (SSRS Expression)

Tags: reporting-services

I have a rectangle.

I want to hide it if a field (X) is NOT NULL.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
=IIF(NOT IsNothing(Fields!filepath.Value), 1, 0)
```

I get the error:

An error occurred during local report processing.

The Hidden expression used in rectangle 'ID2398' returned a data type that is not valid.

Anyone know why I'm having this issue?

Do I need to place the actual field onto the report? I tried it but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using that for the Visibility expression, I believe you need to explicitly use `True`/`False` rather than 1 or 0.  So try:

```
=IIF(NOT IsNothing(Fields!filepath.Value), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer to use `=iff(Fields!filepath.Value IsNot Nothing, Fields!filepath.Value, )` in Textbox/Properties/Visibility/Hide as it is more intuitive for me.